# Magic Cloud Rails Picture does not appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick

I'm using "MAgic cloud" to generate the word cloud in ruby, but I can not get the image to appear in the view.

My function
`

```
  def mgcloud(string)
     words = []
     (Hash[count_words2(string).sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]).each_pair do |key, value|  
       words.push([key, value])
     end
     cloud = MagicCloud::Cloud.new(words, rotate: :free, scale: :log)
     cloud
  end
```

`My View`

```
<%= mgcloud(pages.dados)%>
```

output

```
#<MagicCloud::Cloud:0x007f8a1801da48>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://turnspike.com/2018/01/29/simple-magiccloud-example/) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `cloud = MagicCloud::Cloud.new` instantiates a new object, and when you're doing `<%= something %>` in rails, it's basically outputting `something.to_s`.

Looking at the source for that class (I assume [this is the gem](https://github.com/zverok/magic_cloud/blob/master/lib/magic_cloud/cloud.rb))
What you want to do is something like:

`<%= mgcloud(pages.dados).draw %>`